# Using tcmalloc in my C++ project

Tags: c++, tcmalloc

I'm linking my C++ program to [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) with `-ltcmalloc_minimal` in linux and i have install the `ltcmalloc` lib with `apt-get install libgoogle-perftools-dev`.

Do i need to add any include file to my project source files to enable tcmalloc in my project? Do tcmalloc replaces all the new/free/malloc in all libs used by my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specifically call tcmalloc API - i.e `tc_new`, `tc_free` You don't need to include any headers from tcmalloc. This is because malloc and other memory functions declarations are already included by the call to `include <malloc.h>`. Their definitions are overridden(or aliased) in tcmalloc library. In TCMalloc, the standard API (`new`, `malloc`, `realloc`, `free`, `delete`, etc...) and also POSIX API (such as `posix_memaligned`) are either aliased (in GCC compatible platforms) or overridden (windows, ...). The only thing you need to add is in case of static linkage the libraries `-ltcmalloc_minimal.a` or `-ltcmalloc.a` and it's path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to include the headers because you need the declarations for the functions.

For your second question, I would suggest you read their [documentation](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html)

Comment: That documentation does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

To close this question, i just needed to include the lib in the compiling process, no need to include any header.